# Attaching to an existing Chrome page in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

For background, I'm trying to log-in to a web site using Selenium.  However, I can't seem to navigate through the log-in page of the OAuth provider - in this case, MS.  Even when I've managed it using various techniques of waiting, and so forth, I get stuck in 2FA.

As a result, I've now decided that what I need to do is to log-in to the site manually, and then run the Selenium script.  However, I can't seem to find anywhere that shows how to connect to an existing broser instance:

```
var webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Just launches a new instance.  Is there a way to attach to an existing instance; or, is there a way to navigate an external OAuth provider, such as B2C?

Answer (score 1):

Start chrome as :

```
 C:/pathtochroome/chrome.exe  --remote-debugging-port=1559
```

Add connect to it as:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559")
```

if this doesn't work try:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:1559";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work - it just times out

Comment: @stannage you have to close all chrome browsers before running the code

Comment: first close all brwosers then start chrome  C:/pathtochroome/chrome.exe  --remote-debugging-port=1559

Comment: then do localhost:1559 to verify the port is working